# Question closed dispute

Tags: support

I found a problem in a Sprint Android, and got an answer from Android.StackExchange...

[How do you get carriers to fix android os bugs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8795/how-do-you-get-carriers-to-fix-android-os-bugs)

Strangely, this question was closed as 'not a real question' before I accepted [the answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8795/how-do-you-get-carriers-to-fix-android-os-bugs/8814#8814).

Assuming I am right, and the question is valid, could someone do the right thing and reopen?

### EDIT

Matthew claims my question is not about the android; however, the answer I want to select is in-fact pointing me to the Google Android site so I can file a bug.  If this isn't about android, I'm wondering what is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit "rant-y". I'm sure I understand your frustration; too often these damn carriers ruin what is otherwise an elegant phone OS.

If your question is really "how can I submit an official bug report with Sprint?" then please edit your question to make that clearer (and remove the ranty bits). Knowing how to get past mainline tech support to really report a bug is something other hardcore Android users would want to know. (In fact, a Community Wiki question with answers for each of the carriers would be even more useful.)

If that's not really your question, then please make it clearer what your question actually is. And in either case leave out the rant. (As it says right in the FAQ under "What should I not ask here" is: "it is a rant disguised as a question".)

Comment: first thank you.  Second, if I did not include the bit about interactions with Sprint, everyone will suggest tech support. I was pointing out that normal tech support isn't going to help in this case.  I will endeavor to edit some more for clarity after work

Comment: "Edit" is a remarkably powerful tool....